# RUCM - "Model is not a proper object of class 'SSModel'"

Tags: r

I'm getting the error "Model is not a proper object of class 'SSModel'" when I try to use the predict function in the RUCM package to get predicted future values for my model.

My code is as follows:

```
batData <- read.csv("C:/Users/adsofihadsf/Desktop/Test.csv")
timeSeries <- ts(batData$Accidents, start=c(0, 1), end=c(12, 4), frequency=4)
model <- ucm(timeSeries~0, data = timeSeries, slope = TRUE)
predict(model$model, n.ahead=4)
```

Everything goes fine up until the predict function. And, if I go ahead and check the contents of the model variable, it looks exactly how I'd expect. I've even tried to re-run this against the default R Nile River dataset. It works perfectly there...

```
modelNile <- ucm(Nile~0, data = Nile, slope = TRUE)
predict(modelNile$model, n.ahead = 12)
```

What in the world is going on here?

Data (Test.csv):

```
Accidents,Fuel
192,32.592
238,37.25
232,40.032
246,35.852
185,38.226
274,38.711
266,43.139
196,40.434
170,35.898
234,37.111
272,38.944
234,37.717
210,37.861
280,42.524
246,43.965
248,41.976
269,42.918
326,49.789
342,48.454
257,45.056
280,49.385
290,42.524
356,51.224
295,48.562
279,48.167
330,51.362
354,54.646
331,53.398
291,50.584
377,51.32
327,50.81
301,46.272
269,48.664
314,48.122
318,47.483
288,44.732
242,46.143
268,44.129
327,46.258
253,48.23
215,46.459
263,50.686
319,49.681
263,51.029
206,47.236
286,51.717
323,51.824
306,49.38
230,47.961
304,46.039
311,55.683
292,52.263
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was turning the data into a time series... Replacing the code with the following fixed things quite easily...

```
batData <- read.csv("C:/Users/aosdhfoaidshf/Desktop/Test.csv")
model <- ucm(Accidents~0, data = batData, slope = TRUE)
plot(batData$Accidents)
lines(predict(model), col="blue")
```

Unfortunately, the RUCM [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rucm/rucm.pdf) is very unclear about this. It says the UCM function "decomposes a time series" and the example uses Nile data (which is a time series). It's still a mystery to me why the above code works with the Nile time series, but not with my custom one... but whatever. It works now.